# Db2 query to create users

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to understand if it is possible to create users in DB2 SQL using Query, instead of using useradd commands. What is the query to create user in DB2 and in which table the user details will be stored.

Your response will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 does not have separate users - Db2 uses the users (and groups) available through the operating system.

USERADD is not a Db2 command but a OS one.

So you could generate something with the help of SQL but I do not think this is what you a referring to.